# Storing matching results from a regular expression in an array

Tags: arrays, regex, bash

I am trying to write a simple bash script that would grep for a string in a binary file and then using a regular expression extract all hexadecimal strings. However, I cannot seem to find a way in which I could store the output from the regex in an array which I could later on use to convert all of its elements from hexadecimal to ASCII values.

```
str=$(grep -ra "Html.Exploit.CVE.2015_6073" /var/lib);
hexstr=$([[ $STR =~ (?<=^|[*{};])[A-Fa-f0-9]+(?=$|[*;{}]) ]]);
converted=$(xxd -r -p <<< "$HEXSTR");
echo -e "\e[92m$converted \e[0m"
```

Can I do an `if` statement with a `while` loop in it that would create an array with the hexadecimal strings (returned from the regex) as elements?

## **UPDATE**

---

Current code:

```
#!/bin/bash

str=$(grep -ra "Html.Exploit.CVE.2015_6073" /var/lib);

 if [[ $str =~ (?<=^|[*{};])[A-Fa-f0-9]+(?=$|[*;{}]) ]]; then
      Array+="$str"
 fi

 for hex in "${Array[@]}"; do 
      echo $hex
 done
```

Comment: you must have parentheses around  the `$str` like this `Arrary+=("$str")` in order to added it to the array.

Comment: `=~` doesn't support lookarounds regex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add values to an array like this in bash:

```
 Array+=("$hexstr")
```

Then you can loop through the array like this:

```
 for hex in "${Array[@]}"; do 
      #perform operation to convert hex here
      converted="$(xxd -r -p <<< "$hex")"
 done
```

To correct the `if match` logic you can make a statement like this so the `$hexstr` variable will get set.

```
 if [[ $STR =~ (?<=^|[*{};])[A-Fa-f0-9]+(?=$|[*;{}]) ]]; then
      hexstr="$STR"
 fi
```

Putting this together would look like this:

```
 if [[ $STR =~ (?<=^|[*{};])[A-Fa-f0-9]+(?=$|[*;{}]) ]]; then
      Array+=("$STR")
 fi

 ###Do work
 ###Use For loop etc
```

If you want to shorten your code even more (less code less chances to break) you can do all of the matching in the grep and add to the array like this:

```
 Array=($( grep -ra "Html.Exploit.CVE.2015_6073" /var/lib | grep -oP "(?<=^|[*{};])[A-Fa-f0-9]+(?=$|[*;{}])"))
 ##Do For loop
```

The above will perform your grep and find only matching lines then it will get only the matching value of the regex and store each in the array.

Comment: I did the loop like so as recommended: `for hex in "${Array[@]}"; do 
      converted="$(xxd -r -p <<< "$hex")"
      echo -e "\e[92m$converted \e[0m"
 done`

However, I think the way I store the result from the regex in $hexstr is wrong. Right now it returns nothing upon execution.

Comment: @McJohnson Updated my answer.

Comment: Updated the question with the modified code. It again returns nothing. The grep works, problem seems to be with the storing of the results from the regular expression. Is the `=~` operator actually used in such cases? The regex itself works fine as tested at https://regex101.com/r/eT2pG2/3

Comment: Thanks for the update. It works fine now. Thank you for your time and answer. Accepted and upped.

Comment: Not a problem happy to help.